# mix.options is not a function

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-5, gulp

I've been trying to run PurifyCSS for my Laravel app, but keep getting the "mix.options is not a function" error whenever I run 'gulp' from the command line. mix.styles works just fine though

I understand that this problem happened for a lot of people because they were on old versions of Laravel mix, however I believe I've updated it (eg npm laravel-mix -v returns "3.10.10")

Any advice? Thanks

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.options({ purifyCss: true });

    mix.styles([
        'bootstrap.css',
        'cc.css'
    ]);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you're using `laravel-elixir` package which has been upgraded and renamed to `laravel-mix`. So, install it using `npm install laravel-mix --save-dev` which is at version `1.4.2` as of yet. After install, try this.

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.options({ purifyCss: true });

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

In your `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`

```
// Bootstrap
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

// Write your custom css here
```

Also, Update your `package.json` scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
```

Comment: Thanks!! Really appreciate it

Comment: @user6122500 Happy to help :-)

Comment: Sorry 1 more question - I've put your code into my webpack.mix.js file, and now it is combining and minifying the CSS files successfully; however it is not stripping out unused CSS (eg I created a random #notused {} in the source CSS and that was copied over to the output file). I'm not seeing any errors in the console (it just says "Compiled successfully"). Any tips?

Comment: @user6122500 please confirm that you've the latest install of `purify-css` and `purifycss-webpack` in your dependencies list.

Comment: i think so, npm purify-css -v and npm purify-csswebpack return "3.10.10". Here are the dependencies from my package.json (which I then ran 'npm install' off): {
  "private": true
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "*",
    "purify-css": "*",
    "purifycss-webpack": "*"
  }
}

Comment: @user6122500 I see. After some research, i found that `purify-css` doesn't work when using `styles` method as it just for combining some plain CSS stylesheets into a single file. You have to use sass or less. You can simply import your stylesheets into laravel's provided sass file to make it work. I've updated my answer. Try it

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!